# I want ionCube PHP Loader for Azure website?

Tags: azure, ioncube

I want  ionCube PHP Loader  for run php script on Azure website ? 
How can i do ? , please, help me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I enable Zend Guard Loader extension (ZendLoader.dll) on Azure?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15193837/how-can-i-enable-zend-guard-loader-extension-zendloader-dll-on-azure)

Answer (score 0):

In general, if you can install own binary extensions, then it shall be no problem. It'd be best to consult Azure's faq or contact support for clarification