# How can I enable Zend Guard Loader extension (ZendLoader.dll) on Azure?

Tags: php, azure

I have an azure website running php 5.3 and files encrypted with Zend Guard.  I can't get azure to load ZendGuard extension.  I have followed this advice: 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/silverlining/archive/2012/09/17/using-custom-php-extensions-in-windows-azure-web-sites.aspx

I have an app setting : PHP_EXTENSIONS = bin/ZendLoader.dll

and I have a .user.ini file with 
    upload_max_filesize = 10M

```
[Zend]
zend_loader.enable=1
zend_loader.disable_licensing=0
zend_extension="bin/ZendLoader.dll"
```

the upload_max setting is being taken, so I know the file is being loaded, and the PHP_EXTENSIONS is being shown in PHPinfo as a server var, but no loaded extension.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just wrote a blog post on how you can [Enable ZendGuard in Windows Azure Web Sites](http://blog.syntaxc4.net/post/2013/07/25/enabling-zendguard-encoding-in-windows-azure-web-sites.aspx).

One main different is that ZendLoader is a ZendExtension, which needs an app setting the key **PHP_ZendExtensions** instead of **PHP_Extensions**

This [link](http://forums.iis.net/post/1994318.aspx) describes how to configure ZendGuard in PHP running with FastCGI in IIS.